# add time stamp to django auto_add_now

Tags: django, datetime, modal-dialog

I am saving to instances in my table which have a field `created_at`

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField("Date Submitted", auto_now_add=True) #automatically added when request is created
```

So what happen, the both dates are actually the same, no difference, and when i sort them by `created_at` i actually get the added first at the top, i needed most recent.

I was looking if i could add difference of 2 seconds between the both posts?

### CODE

```
new_project_log = Log(
                user_id=request.user.id,
                project=project,
                project_state_id=Project.NEW_REQUEST,
                role=get_current_role(request))
new_project_log.save()

new_project_log.pk = None
new_project_log.project_state_id = project.project_state_id = Project.AWAITING_STANDARDS

new_project_log.save()
```

Let me know.

Comment: How do you add the instances?

Comment: Please find the code, i have updated.

Comment: I posted my answer. I think they are saved in the same second. That is the problem.

Comment: So we need the exact solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can modify the created_at after.

```
from datetime import timedelta

instance.created_at += timedelta(seconds=2)
```

Comment: Actually i have tried this. Please find `auto_now_add=True` which adds the date Time automatically.

Comment: Yes. But you save the object and then edit the `created_at` and save it again. This way the `auto_now_add` won't trigger anymore.